# Como utilizar mais de 1 'div asp-validation-summary' em uma mesma view Razor?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net, asp.net-core, razor

Possuo uma view Razor que possui dois formulários distintos sendo um de Login e outro de Cadastro de usuários, construi ambos os formulários e inseri como de praxe a tag com `asp-validation-summary`

`<div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger"></div>`

em ambos os formulários, entretanto ao testar identifiquei que ao se retornar uma inconsistência da validação do model de `Login` ou `Cadastro` ambos

`<div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger"></div>`

ficam com a inconsistência. procurei na documentação algo que evita-se este problema, mas não há nada, há alguma solução **Oficial** ou algum **Workaround**?

> Além de inserir ambos os formulários na mesma view, também testei inserindo cada formulário em uma partial view separada mas sem sucesso.

**Tecnologias envolvidas:** Asp.Net Core 2.0 e Razor (View)

Simples código para reprodução:

```
<form asp-controller="Conta" asp-action="Login" autocomplete="off">
    <div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger"></div>

    <input asp-for="Email" placeholder="@Html.DisplayNameFor(x => x.Email)" />
    <span asp-validation-for="Email" class="text-danger"></span>

    <input asp-for="Senha" placeholder="@Html.DisplayNameFor(x => x.Senha)" />
    <span asp-validation-for="Senha" class="text-danger"></span>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Enviar</button>
</form>

<form asp-controller="Conta" asp-action="CadastroCliente" autocomplete="off">
        <div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger"></div>

        <input asp-for="NomeCliente" placeholder="@Html.DisplayNameFor(x => x.NomeCliente)" />
        <span asp-validation-for="NomeCliente" class="text-danger"></span>

        <input asp-for="CPF" placeholder="@Html.DisplayNameFor(x => x.CPF)" />
        <span asp-validation-for="CPF" class="text-danger"></span>

        <input asp-for="EmailCliente" placeholder="@Html.DisplayNameFor(x => x.EmailCliente)" />
        <span asp-validation-for="EmailCliente" class="text-danger"></span>

        <input asp-for="SenhaCliente" placeholder="@Html.DisplayNameFor(x => x.SenhaCliente)" />
        <span asp-validation-for="SenhaCliente" class="text-danger"></span>

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Cadastrar</button>
    </form>
```

Comment: Vc testou em partialview mas com models diferentes? (Um pra cada) e na configuração do asp-validation-summary você tentou assim:<div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>

Comment: @Rafael sim como models diferentes